# Firebase on method not working in javascript

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have a web app that uses firebase. The app posts updates in the realtime database, but when it comes to reading the data, nothing works including the `on` method, knowing that I checked my code on another firebase database for another project and it works perfectly.
The code is:

```
firebase.initializeApp(config);
firebase.database().ref("/").on('value',function(snapshot)
  {console.log(snapshot.val());});
```

Comment: Did you check the JavaScript console of your browser for any errors? My initial guess is that you don't have permission to read the data.

Comment: It probably does not matter, but try `firebase.database().ref()`.

Comment: The console doesn't log anything and I have full read-write permissions

Comment: It turned out that if the authorization permissions are off, you can't read while being authorized

Answer (score 2, accepted):

name should mention like

```
firebase.database().ref("users/").on('value',function(snapshot)
```

Comment: how can this be the answer and be -1 ?